# Export Excel worksheet as PDF using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I keep running into an error 9.

```vb
Dim SavePath    As String
Dim SaveAs      As String
Dim FileName    As String
Dim sDate       As String

'// Save it Path
SavePath = "P:\Price book\SQF Food Safety Management System\Records - Monitoring Forms\Production Records\"

'// File Name
FileName = " - Production Record"

'// Format the on "N2" to YYYY-MM-DD
sDate = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet8").Range("N1"), YYY.MM.DD)

'// Save with File Name & Date & .pdf
SaveAs = sDate & FileName & ".pdf"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'// Export Active Sheet as pdf
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
  SavePath & SaveAs

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

The sDate is out of range.

I want to export the worksheet as a PDF with the date which is in a cell N1 and ' - Production Record' at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try changing the `sDate` definition line in this way:

```
sDate = Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet8").Range("N1").value, "YYY.MM.DD")
```

Comment: @Luke Moody: Didn't you find some time to check the above suggestion? If tested, does it not return what you need?